# Битрикс. Не загружается форма входа в модальное окно

Tags: php, битрикс

Модальные окна реализованы на сайте с помощью плагина jqModal , ниже участок кода который инициализирует форму входа:

```
  $('.'+name+'_frame').jqm({
          trigger: open_trigger,
          onLoad: function( hash ){
          onLoadjqm( name , hash , requestData, selector); },
          ajax: arMShopOptions["SITE_DIR"]+'ajax/auth.php'
   });
```

т.е ищется элемент где $('.form_frame') проверил, все параметры передаются нормально. 
Ниже код вызова jqm:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            jqmEd('enter', 'auth', '.avtorization-call.enter');
        });
```

jqmEd - функция обертка , она принимает только доп параметры.

Вот код файла auth.php к которому делается запрос:

```
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>
<?
global $USER;

if($_GET["auth_service_error"]){
    LocalRedirect(SITE_DIR.'auth/');
}
if(!$USER->IsAuthorized()){?>
    <div id="wrap_ajax_auth">
        <a href="#" class="close jqmClose"><i></i></a>
        <div class="popup-intro">
            <div class="pop-up-title">Вход в личный кабинет</div>
        </div>
        <?
        $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:system.auth.form",
            "mshop",
            Array(
                "REGISTER_URL" => SITE_DIR."auth/registration/",
                "PROFILE_URL" => SITE_DIR."personal/",
                "FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL" => SITE_DIR."auth/forgot-password/",
                "AUTH_URL" => SITE_DIR."ajax/show_auth_popup.php",
                "SHOW_ERRORS" => "Y",
                "POPUP_AUTH" => "Y",
                "AJAX_MODE" => "Y"
            )
        );?>
    </div>
<?}
elseif(strlen($_REQUEST["backurl"])){
    LocalRedirect($_REQUEST["backurl"]);
}
else{
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '/auth/') === false && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '/ajax/auth.php') === false){
        $APPLICATION->ShowHead();
        ?>
        <script>
            jsAjaxUtil.ShowLocalWaitWindow( 'id', 'wrap_ajax_auth', true );
            BX.reload(false)
        </script>
        <?
    }
    else{
        LocalRedirect(SITE_DIR.'personal/');
    }
}
```

и когда мы кликаем по элементу, форма всплывает пустой , т.е данные из auth.php не вставляются. Если попробовать загрузить другой файл , например test.php с тестом hello, то все работает отлично, текст отображается в модальном окне. Но как только подключишь `<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>` то загружается пустота, т.е нечего нет.

Подскажите что может быть не так ? Интересно то , что на другом сайте аналогичный код работает нормально.